# Dispatching Redux Data and Get the State

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I stuck on Redux Implementation during developing an app using React Native and Redux. I do this for the first time and followed [this example](https://snack.expo.io/@samauch/my-chat-redux).

I've already installed Redux and React Native Navigation. I would like to save the state containing data for countries (the user picked a country and would like to keep the choice by the time when it browses to all screens).

Good. I've created a component that could be seen to all screens like this:

```
        LinksScreen.navigationOptions = {
         headerTitle: 'Links',
         headerRight: <CountriesPickButton/>,
       };
```

Next, I visualize the button and wait for a change in the component. By default, it should show primary country. Next, the user clicks on the button and it opens a modal where has a dropdown menu. For example, I show you the default fetching a country:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../../redux/countries'

export default class CountriesPick extends Component {

render() {....  // here is the button and modal, etc. It's work. 
}

 constructor(props, context) {

    super(props, context);

    this.state = store.getState();

    store.subscribe(() => {

      this.setState(store.getState());

    });

    this.defaultCountry(251);
}


async defaultCountry(countryId) {

    return fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        for (const key of Object.keys(responseJson.result)) {
          // this works for current screen: this.setState({ defaultCountry: responseJson.result[key], selectedCountry: responseJson.result[key].country_id });
          store.dispatch({ defaultCountry: responseJson.result[key], selectedCountry: responseJson.result[key].country_id ,  type: 'countries' });

        }

        return responseJson.result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

state = {
  showModal: false,
  countries: [],
  selectedCountry: 0,
  defaultCountry: [], 
  type: 'countries'
  };
  }
```

Without  `store.dispatch({})` I can change the state with the country but it has not to share between screens. That's because I started with Redux.

Here is the Redux code ():

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const defaultState = {
  showModal: false,
  countries: [],
  selectedCountry: 0,
  defaultCountry: [], 
  type: 'countries'
};

function store(state = defaultState) {

  return state;
}

export default createStore(store);
```

Something is not like it should be. When I invoke `store.dispatch({...})` it's not changing the state, it returns the default array. I guess I should use `<Provider></Provider>` in App.js to catch every change but first, I need to understand what I wrong?

Is it connected at all? In the example that I followed, I did not see `connect()`.  Also, I'm not sure I'm using `type` properly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problems here are the following:

1. Example on the link you provided is bad to say the least. Do not follow it
2. You said to be using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), but the code you provided comes from [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation). I suggest using the latter, especially for starters
3. Your createStore code is not going to work, as reducer for the store should be a function of `state` and `action`

With that being said, you should definitely see [Basic Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial) of redux with examples. You will almost never have to do `store.getState()` or `store.dispatch()` while using react with redux, as `react-redux`package (included in the tutorial I linked) will do this for you. You will instead declare dependency between your store state and props your component receives